# Как изменить значение case в switch case при уменьшении ширины экрана?

Tags: css, wordpress

Я использую foreach для вывода постов. Внутри него я вставил switch case для того что бы вывести баннер между рядами постов. Все было бы отлично, но только вот при уменьшении ширины экрана последний (перед баннером) ряд остается не полным.
Так баннер выглядит при ширине 1920:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так при ширине 1400:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что бы баннер выглядел одинаково?

Comment: Ну к PHP это отношения явно не имеет, да и к WordPress.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема решаеться банальным `CSS`. Выводите свои поля обычным `foreach` после цикла вставляете ваш баннер.
Вот так это выглядит.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  width: 100%;

}

.item {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  min-height: 100px;
  order: 4;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">Item block</div>
  <div class="item">Item block</div>
  <div class="item">Item block</div>
  <div class="item">Item block</div>
  <div class="item">Item block</div>
  <div class="item">Item block</div>
  <a class="banner" href="#">Banner</a>
</div>
```